# Limit Spark application from grabbing all the resources in a YARN cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

We (an engineering team) are running an `EMR` cluster with `YARN` and `Spark`. What is typically happening is that when one user submits a heavy memory intensive job, it grabs all the YARN available memory and then all the subsequent users submitted jobs have to wait for that memory to clear (I know that `autoscaling` will solve this problem to a certain extent and we are looking into that, but we would like to avoid a single user occupying all the memory even when the cluster is `autoscale`d to it's full limits).

Is there a way to configure YARN such that any application (`Spark` or otherwise) may not occupy more than, say 75% of available memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties), you can manage the amount of memory allocated to an executor using the parameter: spark.executor.memory